# What could cause an app to be stale when accessing it through CNAME alias?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, dns, amazon-route53, vercel

I have a very strange situation where a stale version of my app is being served only when accessing it through its CNAME alias.

The app is a static node app built with Webpack and hosted on Zeit NOW. If I access it using the direct Zeit URL, I get the most recent version and correct JS assets:

```
https://nates-app.now.sh/index.html -> https://nates-app.now.sh/client/index.eb53e753.js (current)
```

In AWS Route53, I have a CNAME set up to alias `www.nates-app.com` to `https://nates-app.now.sh`. However, pointing my browser to `https://www.nates-app.com` results in a stale `index.html`. What's even stranger, is that the stale index.html page reqeusts stale JS and CSS assets, which also are being returned successfully:

```
https://www.nates-app.com/index.html -> https://www.nates-app.com/client/index.f64812dd.js (stale)
```

The stale version is more than 48 hours old.

Dig shows nearly identical results. `dig nates-app.now.sh` results in the following ANSWER section:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
nates-app.now.sh.   60  IN  A   1.2.3.4
nates-app.now.sh.   60  IN  A   4.3.2.1
```

`dig www.nates-app.com` results in identical output, with only the one (expected) addition showing the CNAME in the `ANSWER` section:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.nates-app.com.  300 IN  CNAME   https://nates-app.now.sh.
nates-app.now.sh.   60  IN  A   1.2.3.4
nates-app.now.sh.   60  IN  A   4.3.2.1
```

I'm not using AWS Cloudfront, or any other CDN for static assets.

I've obviously cleared my browser's cache, and even toggled my VPN off and on. A colleague sees the same thing when accessing the internet from a different ISP.

**So what in the world wide web could be caching a (very) old version of my site's HTML and accompanying assets?**

Comment: I believe this falls within the guidelines of "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development."

Comment: The destination web server is unaware of the CNAME association between the two hostnames -- it doesn't know why the traffic routed to it, as it only sees the incoming `Host` header -- so the very likely explanation is that it is treating the two hostnames as two separate sites, and the question is "why?"  (To illustrate this, create another CNAME pointing to the same place from an entirely different domain of yours and you'll see that the web server has no idea what content to serve, and returns an error or generic page.) Probably a question for the web hosting provider, unrelated to Route 53.

Answer (score 0):

Very weird, When I have experienced similar issue like this, the solution was always refreshing the browser cache or using an incognito mode. Do you still experience the same

Comment: Yes it is the same across multiple browsers with and without incognito mode

Comment: www.nates-app.com.  300 IN  CNAME   https://nates-app.now.sh  . You dont have https when you created the cname right. Your cname must be simply www.nates-app.com.  300 IN  CNAME   nates-app.now.sh.  correct?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

Zeit doesn't support pointing a `CNAME` directly at your Zeit subdomain. You need to configure your domain within the Zeit dashboard and setup a verification text record and assign your `CNAME` to `alias.zeit.co`. The `alias.zeit.co` servers route your `CNAME` to the most current deployment.

It's also possible that, within Zeit's configuration, your domain name is still pointing to an older deployment in your project. Zeit doesn't automatically reassign domain names to new deployments unless you are doing a production deployment, ie., `now --prod` or you've configured it to treat pushes to a git `master` branch as production deployments. In your dashboard, click on `Projects` and then click on the name of your project. If you don't see your domain listed in the most recent deployment, that could be your culprit.